# How to return a value from a c# SignalR client

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have a hub that manages many worker processes. I want to build a UI that lets me connect to this hub and retrieve the processing log from any of these worker processes. Essentially this will be a client wanting to obtain a string from another client. I have been able to get the request from client A sent to client B, but i dont know how to return anything in that response.

I have a simple method in the hub

```
public void GetRunLog(int runid)
{
    JobRunLog log = null;
    JobRunClient client = this.GetClientByRunID(runid);
    if(client != null)
    {
        var rawlog = Clients.Client(client.ConnectionID).GetRunLog();
        log = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JobRunLog>(rawlog);
        Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).GetRunLog(log);
    }
}
```

This request gets picked up by the client, but I dont know how to make it return a value so that `var rawlog` actually contains something. For the moment, this is the best workaround i could come up with.

```
myHubProxy.On("GetRunLog", (uiconnectionid) =>
{
    string connectionid = uiconnectionid;
    myHubProxy.Invoke("ReturnRunLog", run.ID, run.Log, connectionid).ContinueWith(task => {});
});
```

This will then make the worker client send the log back in a separate request with a reference to the client that had requested the log, but it isnt actually returning a respnonse to the initial request. I cant see a way to make this happen. Rather than use Invoke, how would i just return the object directly to the method on the hub that initiated the request?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there SignalR alternative with "return value to server" functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205191/is-there-signalr-alternative-with-return-value-to-server-functionality)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly Hub [doesn't keeps it's state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hubclass):

> Because instances of the Hub class are transient, you can't use them
>   to maintain state from one method call to the next. Each time the
>   server receives a method call from a client, a new instance of your
>   Hub class processes the message. To maintain state through multiple
>   connections and method calls, use some other method such as a
>   database, or a static variable on the Hub class, or a different class
>   that does not derive from Hub.

Try to move the logic into a separate class and store the instance object in a static dictionary related to the connection id (don't forget to clean it). Whenewer call comes to the Hub it repoints it to a appropriate instance,
here is the simplified sample

```
public class TestingLogHub : Hub
{
    public static readonly Dictionary<string, TestInstance> Instances =
                       new Dictionary<string, TestInstance>();

    public void SetParameter(string value)
    {
        Instances[Context.ConnectionId].ContinueWith(value);
    }
    ...
}

public class TestInstance : IDisposable
{
    public TestInstance(string basePath, IHubContext host, string connectionId)
    {...
    }
    public void ContinueWith(string value)
    {
        if (_nextAction == null)
        {
            FinishExecution();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                _nextAction(value);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Error(exception.Message);
                FinishExecution();
            }
        }
    }


    public void RequestParameterFor(Action<string> action, string parameter, string defaultValue = null)
    {
        _nextAction = action;
        _host.Clients.Client(_connectionId).requestParameter(parameter, defaultValue??GetRandomText());
    }
}
```

So when Instance is started it's doing some work, but at the moment it requires some input it executes `RequestParameterFor` that set's the next function to be executed into an instance state and waits for the next call of `ContinueWith`.

it is a bit generic example, in your case you can send back an object and provide it to an instance, and maybe dispose the instance at the end of that request, if that was the only required call

Comment: this is sort of where i was going with the work around. I am assuming then there is no way for the server to get a simple response from the client by just having var response = Clients.Client(conid).somefunction()?

Comment: Yes you are correct, but [you can't use them to maintain state from one method call to the next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hubclass)