# Is there SignalR alternative with "return value to server" functionality?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, ipc, rpc

**My goal:** Pass data do **specific** client who is **connected to server** and get **results** without calling Server method.

I tried use SignalR to do this (because It's very easy tool for me), but I can't get results (now I know why). I am working on ASP.NET Core 3.1.

**My question:** Is there SignalR alternative with "return value to server" functionality (call method with params on target client and get results)?

Comment: Sure this is easy to archive. You just call a client side method with your data, then you do what you want and finally call the server method to pass your response. What is exactly your question here? How to implement this?

Comment: you mean the server to initiate the request to a specific client (what?), and the client should return a result back?

Comment: You need to call a client (send data from server to client) and then do something in the front end and return result right?

Comment: I can't run another method because I call method on specific client, by Web API (my View use only REST Api)

Comment: Does it work with Core 2.0?

Comment: @jdweng , what do you mean?

Comment: @MarioVernari Yes, to client by his ID

Comment: @Kiril1512 Second question, yes

Comment: A lot of people are having issues with Core 3.0 and Core 3.1.  So does code work with Core 2.0?

Comment: @jdweng, my code can work on Core 2.0

Comment: @PawełJamroziak I did that time ago, but not with SignalR: it was pure WebSocket. I don't know if that's possible with SignalR, because it uses the most convenient way to trasnfer data: it could be even a trivial HTTP request.

Comment: @MarioVernari, understood :/ But I don't know how realise something like "client list" using only HTTP requests (maybe If all client's will be individual servers?)

Comment: @PawełJamroziak I think you have only two choices: either each client will poll periodically the same server (thus mimicking an inverse direction req-reply), or you deal with a WebSocket, which creates a true-bidi channel between client and server. However, I dropped the WebSocket usage because they lack a reconnection protocol. Very annoying if you deal with instable connection such mobile phones.

Comment: So is the issue with Core 3.1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SignalR is usually used in a setup where there are multiple clients and a single server the clients connect to. This makes it a normal thing for clients to call the server and expect results back. Since the server usually does not really care about what *individual* clients are connected, and since the server usually broadcasts to a set of clients (e.g. using a group), the communication direction is mostly used for notifications or broadcasts. Single-target messages are possible but there isn’t a built-in mechanism for a request/response pattern.

In order to make this work with SignalR you *will* need to have a way for the client to call back the server. So you will need a hub action to send the response to.

That alone doesn’t make it difficult but what might do is that you will need to link a client-call with an incoming result message received by a hub. For that, you will have to build something.

Here’s an example implementation to get you starting. The `MyRequestClient` is a singleton service that basically encapsulates the messaging and offers you an asynchronous method that will call the client and only complete once the client responded by calling the callback method on the hub:

```cs
public class MyRequestClient
{
    private readonly IHubContext<MyHub> _hubContext;
    private ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, object> _pendingTasks = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, object>();

    public MyRequestClient(IHubContext<MyHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public async Task<int> Square(string connectionId, int number)
    {
        var requestId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var source = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        _pendingTasks[requestId] = source;

        await _hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("Square", nameof(MyHub.SquareCallback), requestId, number);

        return await source.Task;
    }

    public void SquareCallback(Guid requestId, int result)
    {
        if (_pendingTasks.TryRemove(requestId, out var obj) && obj is TaskCompletionSource<int> source)
            source.SetResult(result);
    }
}
```

In the hub, you then need the callback action to call the request client to complete the task:

```cs
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyHub> _logger;
    private readonly MyRequestClient _requestClient;

    public MyHub(ILogger<MyHub> logger, MyRequestClient requestClient)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _requestClient = requestClient;
    }

    public Task SquareCallback(Guid requestId, int number)
    {
        _requestClient.SquareCallback(requestId, number);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }


    // just for demo purposes
    public Task Start()
    {
        var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        _ = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var number = 42;
            _logger.LogInformation("Starting Square: {Number}", number);
            var result = await _requestClient.Square(connectionId, number);
            _logger.LogInformation("Square returned: {Result}", result);
        });
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The `Start` hub action is only for demo purposes to have a way to start this with a valid connection id.

On the client, you then need to implement the client method and have it call the specified callback method once it’s done:

```js
connection.on('Square', (callbackMethod, requestId, number) => {
    const result = number * number;
    connection.invoke(callbackMethod, requestId, result);
});
```

Finally, you can try this out by invoking the `Start` action by a client:

```js
connection.invoke('Start');
```

Of course, this implementation is very basic and will need a few things like proper error handling and support for timing out the tasks if the client didn’t respond properly. It would also be possible to expand this to support arbitrary calls, without having you to create all these methods manually (e.g. by having a single callback method on the hub that is able to complete any task).

Comment: good answer, but the OP specifically asked for a SignalR alternative

Answer (score 0):

Starting in .NET7 there is a new feature called [client results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-results)

Strongly-typed hubs can return values from interface methods:

```
public interface IClient
{
    Task<string> GetMessage();
}

public class ChatHub : Hub<IClient>
{
    public async Task<string> WaitForMessage(string connectionId)
    {
        return await Clients.Client(connectionId).GetMessage();
    }
}
```

Clients return results in their .On(...) handlers, as shown below:
.NET client

```
hubConnection.On("GetMessage", async () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter message:");

    return await Console.In.ReadLineAsync();
});
```